# how to get list of long values in hibernate from the table while casting from bigint to long

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-native-query

I get the following exception when using the `getEvents` method:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long

```
public List<Long> getEvents(Person person) {

    String q = "select new java.lang.Long(te.event_id) "
        + "from teachers_event te"
        + "where te.teachers_id = :personId ";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(q, Long.class);
    query.setParameter("personId", person.getId());
    return (List<Long>) query.getResultList();
}
```

The `teachers_event` table in database connects the id of teacher with the event. I don't map this table to an entity. I only want to get the ids from it. The ids in the PostgreSQL table are `bigint`.
Is there any way to achieve it without making a separate class to map the `TeacherEvents` entity?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: updated the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPA 2.1 there is a feature called "result set mapping".

Basically you have to define a POJO class which would hold the result values (all the values must be passed using the constructor):

```
public class IdResult{

    private Object id;

    public IdResult(Object id){
        this.id = id;
    }

     public Long getLongId(){
        return (Long)id;
     }
}
```

Then you have to declare the mapping on one of your entities (does not matter on which, it just has to be a declated `@Entity`):

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="IdMapping", classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass = IdResult.class, 
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name="id")})
})
```

You would have to use an alias in your query to match the `@ColumnResult` name:

```
select te.event_id as id
...
```

And finally use in the query creation:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(q, IdMapping.class);
return (List<IdResult>) query.getResultList();
```

Then in your service layer you would just use `getLongId()`;

Comment: I accept the answer as it solves the case, however, I was hoping that there is a way to avoid the result set mapping in this particular case.

Comment: would be possible with a standard jpa query, but native queries do not have the direct resultClass in the creation method unfortunatelly.

Comment: how would the standard jpa query look like?

Comment: you would need to map the table as an entity.. but i think that is what you want to ommit

Comment: Yeah, exactly I wanted to avoid the creation of the entity for the table. Finally, I changed the List to store BigIntegers instead of Longs, so that it matches the database schema which I couldn't modify. That way no need for the casting in the query.